# Computing $\int^{2}_{1}x^x \ln x \,dx$ in terms of $\int^{2}_{1}x^x dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> If $\int^{2}_{1}x^x dx=k$, what is: $$\int^{2}_{1}x^x \ln x \,dx ?$$

Is there a logarithmic trick to bring the power of $x$ in front of $x$, or do we simply integrate using parts until a component of the question is equal to $k$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $y=x^x,\ln y=x\ln x\implies \dfrac{d(x^x)}{dx}=y'=x^x(1+\ln x)\implies\int x^x(1+\ln x)\ dx=?$

$$\int x^x\ln x\ dx=\int x^x(\ln x+1)\ dx-\int x^x\ dx=x^x-\int x^x\ dx$$